# Fill Parent Element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a select button with an input on the right.

I'm trying to use bootstrap but I can't seem to make the select fill the input-group-addon.

Any ideas?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<td class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-12 input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <select>
        <option>+351</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support from Bootstrap for this case, but there's a workaround for this problem. Just insert an empty `.input-group-addon` element between your form elements, e.g.:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
```

Here is a working example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control input-group-addon">
    <option>+351</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <input class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: GENIOUS MA FRIEND

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I appreciate an upvote/accept :)